How to trigger() RTK useLazyQuery in a loop that renders components?
Using: RTK and RTKQ
Problem: I am trying to trigger()/fetch a query inside a loop that renders a component list however, it is giving me errors like 'Too many re-renders' or 'data' does not exist.
Code:
  const items = useSelector(({ items }) => items)
  const terms = useSelector(({ terms }) => terms)
  const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] = useLazyGetItemQuery()

  return (
    <>
      <AComponent>
        {terms.map((term) => {
          const { data, error, isError, isLoading, isFetching, status } = result
          trigger(term)

          data && (
            <BComponent key={data.code} item={data} isLoading={isLoading} />
          )
        })}
      </AComponent>
    </>
  )
}

Expecting: I was expecting this component to update, render, and fetch the new term whenever a new term is added to the terms state from another component that is not shown here.
I am thinking it has something to do with the 'data' not being available right away as it has to fetch first. But, how can I solve this if that's the case? And, if it's not, what seems to be the problem?

Issue
The code is triggering the trigger callback during the render as an unintentional side-effect. This creates a render-loop.
Solution
Refactor the code to extract the mapped logic and useLazyGetItemQuery into a React component that is mapped to so that the trigger function can be used in a useEffect hook and properly called during the component lifecycle.
Example:
const BComponentWrapper = ({ term }) => {
  const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] = useLazyGetItemQuery();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (term) {
      trigger(term);
    }
  }, [term, trigger]);

  const { data, error, isError, isLoading, isFetching, status } = result;

  return <BComponent item={data} isLoading={isLoading} />;
};

  const items = useSelector(({ items }) => items)
  const terms = useSelector(({ terms }) => terms)

  return (
    <AComponent>
      {terms.map((term) => (
        <BComponentWrapper key={term} term={term} />
      ))}
    </AComponent>
  );
};

Since you don't appear to be conditionally triggering the query endpoint it might just make more sense to use the regular query hook.
Example:
const BComponentWrapper = ({ term }) => {
  const {
    data,
    error,
    isError,
    isLoading,
    isFetching,
    status
  } = useGetItemQuery(term, { skip: !term });

  return <BComponent item={data} isLoading={isLoading} />;
};

  const items = useSelector(({ items }) => items)
  const terms = useSelector(({ terms }) => terms)

  return (
    <AComponent>
      {terms.map((term) => (
        <BComponentWrapper key={term} term={term} />
      ))}
    </AComponent>
  );
};

